# Show full P4V log

Tags: perforce, p4v

Anyone know how to show the full log in P4V?

I am seeing in my log

```
p4 revert -a somefile somefile {9 more items}
```

How do I see these 9 other items?

Comment: Did you try looking in the Perforce server's log?

Comment: Bryan Pendleton do you think the perforce admin is asking questions about how to view the p4v log?  Would you care to offer the steps of viewing the server log, aka, a solution?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way.

The next best thing is switching on the output logging, using P4V's *Edit* | *Preferences* | *Logging* | *Show p4 command output for file operations*. With that, a command like yours would produce a log along the lines of

```
p4 revert -a somefile somefile {9 more items}
//depot/somefile#12 - was edit, reverted
//depot/mercury#1 - was edit, reverted
//depot/venus#2 - was edit, reverted
//depot/earth#3 - was edit, reverted
//depot/mars#4 - was edit, reverted
//depot/jupiter#5 - was edit, reverted
//depot/saturn#6 - was edit, reverted
//depot/uranus#7 - was edit, reverted
//depot/neptune#8 - was edit, reverted
//depot/pluto#9 - was delete, reverted
```

I've also tried switching on logging into file but that gives the same output (plus timestamps).

Comment: The nice part about the "Logging to a file" option is that it's available after you close P4V (up to the file-size limit you set).